# Обработка событий во Фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment

Начал изучать Фрагменты и столкнулся с тем, что надо повесить слушатель на кнопку (в данном случае это картинка). Обычно я писал через onClick (View V) и в разметке указывал метод, но знаю, что в Фрагментах это не работает. Если я вешаю слушатель анонимно, то все работает, но я хочу чтоб Фрагмент `implements View.OnClickListener` и был один метод, где по ID выяснять, что за кнопка и тогда уже обрабатывать. Короче не догоняю, что указывать в скобках   `imageViewRight.setOnClickListener(!!!!!!);`

Код ниже работает но не удобно.

```
imageViewRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{}
```

и переопределяете метод onClick(); в чем проблема?

Comment: Не могу повесить слушатель на кнопку!  imageViewLeft.setOnClickListener(this); - не работает, подчеркивается this в скобках

Comment: Ой, заработало. Удалил onClick() и заново прописал implements View.OnClickListener{} и заработало. Видно глюк был или "программирование - это магия". Извиняюсь, думал там не this а что-то другое надо указывать.

Comment: Во фрагменте вы вызываете метод `activity`, поэтому вместо `this` нужно прописывать `getActivity()`

Comment: Это да, но вопрос был про привязку обработчика к кнопке, getActivity() - не вариант. Вопрос закрыт.